# C++ destructor format

Tags: c++, destructor

```
 void arrayList<T>::erase(int theIndex) {
            // valid index, shift elements with higher index
            copy(element + theIndex + 1, element + listSize, element + theIndex);

            element[--listSize].~T(); // invoke destructor 
        }
```

The code  `element[--listSize].~T()` looks strange. It is used to delete the dynamically allocated element. Does any know why we can use this syntax?

**EDIT**

The problem is solved.

Comment: What do you mean by "why"?  We can use this syntax because the standard says so!  Do you actually mean "what is this useful for?".  Note that your example code will do bad things.

Comment: IMO this code has problems. Where did you find it?

Comment: He probably asking why destructor is called explicitly in this case. It means that destructor is not called automatically which makes me look for section of code that makes it necessary to invoke D-tors implicitly. It should be placement new or something.

Comment: This code is from the book http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaac/ in chapt 5.

Comment: @Sean: Well, at the very least, this code is going to cause problems when `arrayList::~arrayList()` runs, as the `delete[]` is going to call the destructors of all elements in the array, including ones that may already have had the destructor explicitly called on them in `erase()`.

Comment: @Sean: As Oli points out, your code is broken, but you could fix it with an allocator used similarly to how vector and other containers do.  (It doesn't necessarily need to be a template parameter and you can use std::allocator directly, if you don't want to allow allocator customization.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly calling the destructor is useful in cases where you want to properly destruct the object, but not deallocate it's memory by using delete (or delete[]) directly, such as inside some custom memory manager. It should not be used very often though.

Answer (score 5):

That would be useful if you have allocated memory for `elements[i]` using `placement new` operator. See [What is "placement new" and why would I use it?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) for details.

Answer (score 3):

> Does any know why we can use this syntax?

We use it to invoke the destructor on an object allocated with [placement new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba.aspx), generally. See also [this page](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html).

Comment: Not at all. You can use it to destruct an object allocated with 'standard' new

Comment: @MeDiCS: You can, but it won't free the memory used by the object.

Comment: @MeDiCS: Yes, you can, but that is a very uncommon usage scenario and potentially dangerous, because you must then ensure that a valid object gets properly put back into that spot if/before somebody delete's it. I edited my answer to hopefully clarify that I'm talking about a common case rather than the only case.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Either way, directly calling some object's destructor won't free it's memory, be it allocated with new, placement new, malloc or a custom allocator, but this syntax is valid for any of those cases.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Right, but you can use free to deallocate what new allocated, considering that you explicitly called the destructor, no? I've heard plenty of warnings about mixing new/delete and malloc/free, but granted that someone is properly aware of their differences, mixing them seems completely valid, though uncommon.

Comment: @Sion: Although `new`/`delete` may typically be implemented in terms of `malloc`/`free`, I believe the behaviour of `free`-ing a pointer obtained by `new` is undefined, and is definitely bad style.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct they are explicitly invoking the destructor ...

However you can fix all of the problems with this implementation by throwing it out and using `std::vector` or `std::list` instead!

Answer (score 2):

> The code element[--listSize].~T() looks strange. It is used to delete the dynamically allocated element. Does any know why we can use this syntax?

It is used to *destroy* that object; this is probably what you meant, but "delete" has other meanings in C++.  You need to do this if you construct each item manually.

You can use this syntax because it is specifically allowed by the language.  The opposite of a manual destructor call is placement new.